# visual studio 2013 before lines number blank vertical space

Tags: visual-studio-2013

There is suddenly a wide space before the line number, and I don't know how to make this disappears. It is really annoying.

I tried to look up the Options, but can't find the way to solve it. What is this blank for, and how can I just make it disappear? It used to have nothing before line number.

Comment: how about a screenshot?

Comment: I cannot upload the screenshot.@ojf

Comment: I finally solved it by reset user data.@ojf